# OpenSource alternatives on XCloner

Tags: wordpress, drupal, joomla, open-source

Is there any existing alternative on XCloner for Joomla or WP?

Sultan

Comment: This seems more appropriate for the webmasters Stack Exchange, http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/, since it isn't about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude, check xcloner.com , that software is free to Download

Answer (score 1):

For Joomla, [Akeeba Backup](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/backup/1606). It is far better than any other backup component/plugin out there. I use it on every single site for myself/clients. I had to recover the website once, process was smooth... recovered the website under 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

someone told me about the wordpress plugin called Really Static which allow to make static sites by using wordpress. maybe this is an alternate to xcloner.

best regards

Comment: Could you add a link to that plugin to your answer?